# Creating conda environment return code 127

Tags: python, conda, anaconda3

I tried during multiples days to create a conda environment with an yml file without success.

Below there is the execution result when I try to use the command to create my environment:
`conda env create -f iml_env.yml`

This is the execution result:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): / WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(556): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1
done
Solving environment: done

Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: - /home/matteo/anaconda3/envs/iml/bin/.widgetsnbextension-post-link.sh: line 1: /home/matteo/anaconda3/envs/iml/bin/jupyter-nbextension: No such file or directory

done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(945): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::widgetsnbextension-3.5.2-py310hff52083_1'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::widgetsnbextension-3.5.2-py310hff52083_1
location of failed script: /home/matteo/anaconda3/envs/iml/bin/.widgetsnbextension-post-link.sh
==> script messages <==
/home/matteo/anaconda3/envs/iml/bin/.widgetsnbextension-post-link.sh: line 1: /home/matteo/anaconda3/envs/iml/bin/jupyter-nbextension: No such file or directory

==> script output <==
stdout: 
stderr: 
return code: 127

()
```

Now I tried many things to solve this issue but it won't install. During the first days launching this command was only printing to the line:"Solving environment: done" and then crashed my computer, but now I get the previous error message.

So do you have any idea to help me create this environment please ?

Here is the yml file :

```
name: iml
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
  - conda-forge/label/broken
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  # Scientific/numeric libraries
  - numpy
  - scipy
  - scikit-learn
  - scikit-image
  - pandas
  # Plotting
  - matplotlib
  - seaborn
  # GPU / Automatic diff / optimisation
  - numba
  # Utils
  - tqdm
  - click
  # Jupyter
  - qgrid
  # Node
  - nodejs
  - pip
  - pip:
    - torch
    - torchvision
    - opencv-python
    - imutils
    - jupyterlab==4.0.2
    - ipywidgets
```

I tried to install it "manually" package by package but at some point I got the previous error message.
I also tried to remove "conda-forge" and "conda-forge/label/broken" from the yml without success. I tried to create the env with anaconda-navigator but it crashed anaconda-nav and I tried to launch the command after updating everything all my computer but still didn't succeed.

What can I try next please ? Also I'm on Ubuntu.